# Jenkins gives error "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded"?

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

While Building a project in jenkins I am getting an Error of OutofBoundMemory.
the log is like this..

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
    at org.sonar.sslr.internal.vm.Machine.createNode(Machine.java:256)
    at org.sonar.sslr.internal.vm.Instruction$RetInstruction.execute(Instruction.java:305)
    at org.sonar.sslr.internal.vm.Machine.execute(Machine.java:162)
    at org.sonar.sslr.internal.vm.Machine.execute(Machine.java:106)
    at org.sonar.sslr.internal.vm.Machine.parse(Machine.java:84)
    at org.sonar.sslr.parser.ParseRunner.parse(ParseRunner.java:45)
    at com.sonar.sslr.api.typed.ActionParser.parse(ActionParser.java:102)
    at com.sonar.sslr.api.typed.ActionParser.parse(ActionParser.java:91)
    at org.sonar.php.PHPAnalyzer.nextFile(PHPAnalyzer.java:71)
    at org.sonar.plugins.php.PHPSensor.analyseFile(PHPSensor.java:142)
    at org.sonar.plugins.php.PHPSensor.analyseFiles(PHPSensor.java:124)
    at org.sonar.plugins.php.PHPSensor.analyse(PHPSensor.java:115)
    at org.sonar.batch.phases.SensorsExecutor.executeSensor(SensorsExecutor.java:58)
    at org.sonar.batch.phases.SensorsExecutor.execute(SensorsExecutor.java:50)
    at org.sonar.batch.phases.AbstractPhaseExecutor.execute(AbstractPhaseExecutor.java:83)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ModuleScanContainer.doAfterStart(ModuleScanContainer.java:192)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:142)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:127)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scan(ProjectScanContainer.java:241)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:236)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:226)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:142)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:127)
    at org.sonar.batch.task.ScanTask.execute(ScanTask.java:47)
    at org.sonar.batch.task.TaskContainer.doAfterStart(TaskContainer.java:86)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:142)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:127)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.GlobalContainer.executeTask(GlobalContainer.java:106)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.executeTask(Batch.java:119)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.batch.BatchIsolatedLauncher.execute(BatchIsolatedLauncher.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
```

Even the build continues for I guess long time.. I am using sonarqube runner
What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

In the build step's "JVM Options" input, you need to specify more memory (than the default) for the process. Here's what that might look like:

> -Xmx2g -Xms512m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m

Note that you should adjust these values based on your system resources.

Comment: WARN: [JOURNAL_FLUSHER] WARNING Journal flush operation took 13,180ms last 8 cycles average is 1,647ms I get this warning. I have set the values to 1024. Can you please tell what does it mean